# Rails console default environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rvm-capistrano

On my development machine:

```
$ bundle exec rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.3)
1.9.3p194 :001 > Rails.env
 => "development"
```

This is expected. So far, so good.

Yet on my production server (to which I have deployed using Capistrano), I get exactly the same result:

```
$ bundle exec rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.3)
1.9.3p194 :001 > Rails.env
 => "development"
```

On either machine, I can instead do:

```
$ bundle exec rails console production
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.3)
1.9.3p194 :001 > Rails.env
 => "production"
```

My question is: on the production server, shouldn't `bundle exec rails console` load the production environment by default, instead of the development environment? And if not, why not?

Comment: Thanks. This answered my question on how to run rails console as production. It does not follow the same pattern as rails server -e production.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The rails executable can't know which environment should run on which machine.

you can put `export RAILS_ENV=production` in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` file of the user you want to start the console with.

Answer (score 5):

RAILS_ENV is a variable like any other which will always default to development

if you like you can always open up '~/.bash_profile' on the production server and add this:

```
 alias sc="bundle exec rails console production"
```

then run `source ~/.bash_profile` to reload that file for your terminal session and you can just call `sc` to load up console.