# How can I make a custom environment in rails a default environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i `created` a custom staging environment in my rails app by adding new file `config/environments/staging.rb`, same as `config/environments/development.rb` 
  and then added database config `config/database.yml`

```
staging:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/staging.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

now, i want to make `staging` the `default environment` of my rails application instead of development.How to achieve it?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10796870/635033) answer out by @jigfox. I believe it's what you' re looking for.

Comment: @gtzilgkakis, adding RAILS_ENV in ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile file of the user. will make this application depent on the console, shouldn't  it just work independent of  ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile file?

Comment: @SachinSingh just want to know..does any answers help you  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you have to set environment variable in `.bashrc` like

```
  export RAILS_ENV=staging
```

because `rails` is fully dependent on environment variable. But like you said

> adding RAILS_ENV in ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile file of the user. will make this application depent on the console, shouldn't it just work independent of ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile file?

Obviously, this is another option. Include this line at the top of `config/boot.rb`

```
ENV["RACK_ENV"] = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || ENV['RACK_ENV'] || "staging"
```

This will work everywhere. I have tested in following places

1. Rails 4
2. Rake
3. Server
4. Console
5. dbconsole
6. It will pick the environment if it is set in `bashrc` or `zshrc` etc.

Comment: @SachinSingh thanks a lot. Do the test whenever you get the time, if the answer satisfy your criteria .. please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in your `application.rb` after `Bundler.require` statement

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'staging'
```

Comment: this is incorrect. it doesn't change environment completely. I just tested this with `rake`, rake picks `development` environment.

Answer (score 0):

I have put 
    ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'custom_development'
in boot.rb at the last.  It worked.

I have tested

- rake
- server
- console
- dbconsole

All Worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I edit file `.zshrc` (in other cases file `.bashrc`):

```
vi ~/.zshrc
```

or

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

And add this line:

```
export RAILS_ENV="staging"
```

After environment `staging` runs by `rails s`.