# Rake not using the same environment value as phusion passenger setting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, passenger

In my vhost, I have:

```
<Directory /var/www/prod/myapp/myapp/public>
  ...
  RailsEnv production
  ...
</Directory>
```

and while any code dependent on it being `production` is correctly running there in the app itself (ex: display the Google Analytics code if `Rails.env.production?`), when I run `rake about` from `/var/www/prod/myapp/myapp`, I get:

```
Application root          /var/www/prod/myapp/myapp
Environment               development
Database adapter          mysql2
```

which means that I have to prefix any deployment related rake stuff with `RAILS_ENV=production`. Granted, it's all in a deployment script at this point so it doesn't matter much, but why isn't Rake aware that it's production? Shouldn't the Passenger setting be enough? And if not, how do I fix it so I won't need to specify the environment manually?

Side-note: I am running the development instance of the app on the same box, with Environment set to development in its corresponding vhost configuration.

EDIT: Phusion Passenger version 4.0.20

Comment: Are you using Capistrano ? rvm ? Both ?

Comment: rvm, yes, Capistrano, no.

Comment: Maybe le problem comes from your deployment. What are you using for ?

Comment: Re-read what I posted. My deployment script has no issue whatsoever because it is explicitly specifying the RAILS_ENV variable for the commands. The question is whether or not this is necessary at the rake level given the configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rake is entirely unaware of passenger's configuration. It doesn't even know that you're using passenger. Since it isn't launched by passenger, it would have to (assuming it knew you were using apache/passenger) parse the apache config files to find this out, which would get pretty complicated, especially in the presence of multiple apps.

You could set this in one of your shell's startup files, however that doesn't sound like a good idea if you have multiple environments on the same machine.

You could stick

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV']='production'
```

At the top of one of Rails' startup files - boot.rb seems to do the trick. This would make passenger's setting ineffective though, and obviously you would only want to do this on the production deploy of your script.

Personally (especially on a machine with multiple environments in action) I'd stick to typing RAILS_ENV=production.

Answer (score 0):

> but why isn't Rake aware that it's production?

Because `rake` and all `rails` related commands  internally do this

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || ENV['RACK_ENV'] || "development"
```

which means that if you didnt have `RAILS_ENV` or `RACK_ENV` environment, then it will use `development` environment by default.

> Shouldn't the Passenger setting be enough?

NO. `Passenger` setting is just for making your app up/live in desire or say virtual environment. It doesn't change any system configuration.

> And if not, how do I fix it so I won't need to specify the environment manually?

That's very easy.  Just set environment variable. If you are using `bash` (normally people do) you can simple do this

```
echo "export RAILS_ENV=production" >> ~/.bashrc ; source ~/.bashrc
```

This will make your server as `rails production` server, so if you run `rails c` or `rake db:migrate` etc or any `rails` or `rake` command it will run in `production` server for all available applications.

> I am running the development instance of the app on the same box, with Environment set to development in its corresponding vhost configuration.

This is a problem. If you set the above environment variable, then whenever you run any code like `rake db:migrate` inside this app ..that will run in `production` environment. To avoid this either you dont set environment variable or specify environment on every command.  There is one hack available . Include this line at the top of `config/boot.rb`

```
  ENV["RACK_ENV"] = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || ENV['RACK_ENV'] || "development"
```

Future reading : [How can I make a custom environment in rails a default environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674251/how-can-i-make-a-custom-environment-in-rails-a-default-environment/22119688#22119688)