# Delayed_job restarting manually works, but not via crontab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, delayed-job

If I run my script manually, i.e. `sh /home/deploy/scripts/cleanup.sh`, everything works fine, but when executing the same script via crontab, the delayed_job part does not work (everything else works!)

```
# Restart all processes
cd ~/apps/kosher/current
~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec pumactl -S /home/deploy/apps/kosher/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state -F /home/deploy/apps/kosher/shared/puma.rb stop
~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec puma -C /home/deploy/apps/kosher/shared/puma.rb --daemon
if RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job restart
 then 
  echo "kosher delayed_job restarted" >> /home/deploy/scripts/cleanup.log
 else
  echo "kosher delayed_job restart failed" >> /home/deploy/scripts/cleanup.log
fi
```

I tried to use `~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec bin/delayed_job -n 1 restart` instead of `RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job restart`, but then I receive an error, stating, that I'm missing the listen-gem:

```
bundler: failed to load command: bin/delayed_job (bin/delayed_job)
LoadError: Could not load the 'listen' gem. Add `gem 'listen'` to the development group of your Gemfile
```

However, my Gemfile does indeed include the gem.

Why can't I restart delayed_job via crontab?

Comment: You should run this command from the application directory. Try this - `cd /path/to/application/dir && RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job restart`

Comment: Otherwise give full path for delayed job binary file -    `RAILS_ENV=production /path/to/application/dir/bin/delayed_job restart`

Comment: Thank you for your response. But am I not doing it already? In the first line, I switch to the current directory, on the fourth I restart DJ.

Comment: My mistake. Anyway it has nothing to do with cron job. It seems like issue with environment settings/gem loading reference. Did you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663706/loaderror-could-not-load-the-listen-gem-rails-5), might help .

Comment: Great help, thank you! The 'bad' workaround, using `gem 'listen', '~> 3.1.5'` helped me indeed.

Comment: Welcome, Glad to hear that you got it working.