# LoadError: Could not load the 'listen' gem (Rails 6)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, listen

Similar question on SO, but dealing with rails 5.  This instance: Rails 6.0.3 with VPS in development.

Running

```
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rails assets:precompile
```

on the server, or `cap development deploy`locally to deploy lead to the fact that listen appears to be hidden from vue.

Server:

```
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rails assets:precompile
rails aborted!
LoadError: Could not load the 'listen' gem. Add `gem 'listen'` to the development group of your Gemfile
```

local deploying:

```
  01 rake aborted!
  01 LoadError: Could not load the 'listen' gem. Add `gem 'listen'` to the development group of your Gemfile
  01 /home/deploy/zappa/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
  01 /home/deploy/zappa/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  ...
  01 Caused by:
  01 LoadError: cannot load such file -- listen
```

but here's the thing:

```
group :development do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.4'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
```

Commenting out the gem from the Gemfile predictably fails; I assume rails wants to know about changes and only act upon those.

Running `RAILS_ENV=development bundle install` returns a clue:

```
Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
```

So how does one go about making `listen` gem visible?

Moving the gem call out of the `development` block and into the global block allows `RAILS_ENV=development bundle install` to run on the remote server.  Now the listen gem is installed and the deployment can proceed with compilation.  *this is a hack, as listen is meant only for development mode; see answer below*

Comment: What does `bundle config` list for the `without` setting? Does it include `development` when it shouldn't? See https://bundler.io/guides/groups.html

Comment: You are correct. `Set for your local app (/home/deploy/zappa/releases/20210113174140/.bundle/config): [:development, :test]`  In essence saying that `Bundler.require(:default, :development)` or `bundle install --with development` should be invoked.  I mistakenly assumed it was obvious if calling `RAILS_ENV=development bundle install` (I had not encountered this problem with Rails 5)?

Comment: This appears to be the same issue, for Rails 5: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663706/loaderror-could-not-load-the-listen-gem-rails-5

Comment: Discussion here: https://github.com/guard/listen/issues/530

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the most direct way to overcome the issue is by adding

```
set :bundle_without, %w{test}.join(':')
```

to the `deploy/development.rb` configuration file as per the [capistrano instructions](https://github.com/capistrano/bundler#usage).

The default setting is:

```
set :bundle_without, %w{development test}.join(':')
```

which is counter-intuitive for development environment.
The error message is also misleading:

```
LoadError: Could not load the 'listen' gem. Add `gem 'listen'` to the development group of your Gemfile
```