# cannot load such file -- listen (LoadError) on bundle exec rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ruby-on-rails-6

Every time I try to run `bundle exec rails console`, I get the `cannot load such file -- listen (LoadError)` on production, however, the rails server(puma) is running and APIs are working.
The code is deployed on ElasticBeanstalk and migration files have run successfully and tables created on `RDS`.
The system config is:

```
Ruby 2.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2
rails version: 6.1
```

I have no clue why is this trying to load the listener on prod.
I do not want to add listener gem to my prod env. Here is my `Gemfile`

```
group :development do
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
```

Adding full trace below:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-... current]$ bundle exec rails c
Traceback (most recent call last):
    60: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
    59: from bin/rails:9:in `require'
    58: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    57: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
    56: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    55: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    54: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    53: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    52: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:101:in `perform'
    51: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:15:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    50: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:28:in `require_environment!'
    49: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/application.rb:367:in `require_environment!'
    48: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
    47: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
    46: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
    45: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
    44: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
    43: from /var/app/current/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    42: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/application.rb:391:in `initialize!'
    41: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    40: from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    39: from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    38: from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    37: from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    36: from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    35: from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    34: from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    33: from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    32: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
    31: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
    30: from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    29: from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    28: from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    27: from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    26: from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    25: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    24: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    23: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    22: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:570:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    21: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:570:in `each'
    20: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:571:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    19: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
    18: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
    17: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
    16: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
    15: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
    14: from /var/app/current/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    13: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:234:in `configure'
    12: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:234:in `instance_eval'
    11: from /var/app/current/config/environments/development.rb:57:in `block in <top (required)>'
    10: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
     9: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
     8: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
     7: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
     6: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
     5: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/evented_file_update_checker.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
     3: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
     2: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
     1: from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
/var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require': cannot load such file -- listen (LoadError)
```

If I try to run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c` I get

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory (PG::ConnectionBad)
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Please note I'm using `rds` and migrations are successful.

Comment: It seems the same problem. I hope this may help you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663706/loaderror-could-not-load-the-listen-gem-rails-5