# Error while running "rails generate active_record:session_migration"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, redmine

I run this command:

```bash
rails generate active_record:session_migration
```

And I get this error:

```
/var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require': cannot load such file -- listen (LoadError)
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/evented_file_update_checker.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
        from /opt/redmine-5.0.3/config/environments/development.rb:58:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/railtie.rb:234:in `instance_eval'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/railtie.rb:234:in `configure'
        from /opt/redmine-5.0.3/config/environments/development.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:571:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:570:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:570:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:391:in `initialize!'
        from /opt/redmine-5.0.3/config/environment.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:367:in `require_environment!'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:28:in `require_environment!'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:15:in `require_application_and_environment!'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/commands/generate/generate_command.rb:21:in `perform'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I added this to my `Gemfile`:

```rb
gem 'activerecord-session_store'
```

Then I ran:

```bash
bundle install
```

Then I ran:

```bash
rails generate active_record:session_migration
```

And I get that error message. **Any help would be most appreciated.**

The server is ubuntu 20.04 with a separate mysql server also running on 20.04.

```
Environment:
  Redmine version                5.0.3.stable
  Ruby version                   3.0.2-p107 (2021-07-07) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
  Rails version                  6.1.7
  Environment                    production
  Database adapter               Mysql2
  Mailer queue                   ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::AsyncAdapter
  Mailer delivery                smtp
Redmine settings:
  Redmine theme                  Redmine-evolution-classic (includes JavaScript)
SCM:
  Git                            2.34.1
  Filesystem                     
Redmine plugins:
  easy_baseline                  2.0
  easy_gantt                     2.0
  easy_gantt_pro                 2.0
  redmine_agile                  1.6.4
  redmine_checklists             3.1.21
  redmine_contacts               4.3.6
  redmine_contacts_helpdesk      4.2.0
  redmine_dmsf                   3.0.8
  redmine_zenedit                2.0.3
  redmineup_tags                 2.0.12
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663706/loaderror-could-not-load-the-listen-gem-rails-5

Comment: OK, that helped, thank you. I used 
 
bundle config --delete without
bundle config --delete with
bundle install